# Given $x,y>0$ and $x+y=1$. Find the minimum $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{x}{y+1}$

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

I tried, such as differentiation, but failed.

Q: Given $x,y>0$ and $x+y=1$. Find the minimum of 
$$\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{x}{y+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Since $x+y=1$, then try with $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{x}{2-x}=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{2}{2-x}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Notice, substituting $y=1-x$, we get  $$\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{x}{y+1}=\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{x}{1-x+1}=\frac{2-x+x^2+x}{(x+1)(2-x)}$$  $$=\frac{x^2+2}{x+2-x^2}$$

Now, differentiating w.r.t. $x$, we get $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2+2}{x+2-x^2}\right)=\frac{(x+2-x^2)(2x)-(x^2+2)(1-2x)}{(x+2-x^2)^2}=\frac{x^2+8x-2}{(x+2-x^2)^2}$$
setting derivative equal to zero, we get $$x^2+8x-2=0$$ 
I hope you can take it from here